# How to go to definition for PostgreSQL functions?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there a support in pgAdmin or another IDE environment that allows one to "go to definition" of a SQL function?

I am chasing a chain of PL/PGSQL and SQL function calls in a PostgreSQL extension, and often got lost while switching between multiple locations in the source files. This makes me wonder if there is some support in the SQL world similar to the `go to definition` function in Eclipse (Ctrl + Click) and many other IDEs/languages.

Comment: Do you mean internal SQL functions like `COUNT()` and `MAX()` or user defined functions?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I mean user defined functions, which I may need to modify.

Comment: For functions that you have created, using `\df+ function_name` in psql will show source code as well. For functions from extensions, not sure. Probably not.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks. I not only want to see the code, but also want to jump to the right source file and edit the code, just as Eclipse's "Ctrl+Leftclick" .